# Sending hashmap from java to react native

Tags: react-native

I have a hashmap that contains
Map<String, List<Custom_object> = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

The data gets filed in this map, and I need to send the updated map data to react native JS bridge. How can I achieve the same?

Thanks in advance,
Siva

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually convert my Custom Object to json String then I parse it to writableMap and return it like below.

```
@ReactMethod
    public void yourBridgeMethod(final ReadableMap argument, final Promise promise) {

    
try {
                    Object x = getMapCustom;
                    final Gson gson = new Gson();
                    final String response = gson.toJson(x);
                    WritableMap returnMap = this.util.convertJsonToMap(new JSONObject(response));
                    promise.resolve(returnMap);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    promise.reject("401", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }

}
```

You could create a util class with this methods to handle your conversions

```
    public WritableMap convertJsonToMap(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
        WritableMap map = new WritableNativeMap();

        Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = iterator.next();
            Object value = jsonObject.get(key);
            if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                map.putMap(key, convertJsonToMap((JSONObject) value));
            } else if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                map.putArray(key, convertJsonToArray((JSONArray) value));
                if (("option_values").equals(key)) {
                    map.putArray("options", convertJsonToArray((JSONArray) value));
                }
            } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
                map.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
            } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
                map.putInt(key, (Integer) value);
            } else if (value instanceof Double) {
                map.putDouble(key, (Double) value);
            } else if (value instanceof String) {
                map.putString(key, (String) value);
            } else {
                map.putString(key, value.toString());
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    public WritableArray convertJsonToArray(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {
        WritableArray array = new WritableNativeArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            Object value = jsonArray.get(i);
            if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                array.pushMap(this.convertJsonToMap((JSONObject) value));
            } else if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                array.pushArray(convertJsonToArray((JSONArray) value));
            } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
                array.pushBoolean((Boolean) value);
            } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
                array.pushInt((Integer) value);
            } else if (value instanceof Double) {
                array.pushDouble((Double) value);
            } else if (value instanceof String) {
                array.pushString((String) value);
            } else {
                array.pushString(value.toString());
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    public JSONObject convertMapToJson(ReadableMap readableMap) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        ReadableMapKeySetIterator iterator = readableMap.keySetIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNextKey()) {
            String key = iterator.nextKey();
            switch (readableMap.getType(key)) {
                case Null:
                    object.put(key, JSONObject.NULL);
                    break;
                case Boolean:
                    object.put(key, readableMap.getBoolean(key));
                    break;
                case Number:
                    object.put(key, readableMap.getDouble(key));
                    break;
                case String:
                    object.put(key, readableMap.getString(key));
                    break;
                case Map:
                    object.put(key, convertMapToJson(readableMap.getMap(key)));
                    break;
                case Array:
                    object.put(key, convertArrayToJson(readableMap.getArray(key)));
                    break;
            }
        }
        return object;
    }

    public JSONArray convertArrayToJson(ReadableArray readableArray) throws JSONException {

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < readableArray.size(); i++) {
            switch (readableArray.getType(i)) {
                case Null:
                    break;
                case Boolean:
                    array.put(readableArray.getBoolean(i));
                    break;
                case Number:
                    array.put(readableArray.getDouble(i));
                    break;
                case String:
                    array.put(readableArray.getString(i));
                    break;
                case Map:
                    array.put(convertMapToJson(readableArray.getMap(i)));
                    break;
                case Array:
                    array.put(convertArrayToJson(readableArray.getArray(i)));
                    break;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
```

Comment: Object x = getMapCustom; so this getMapCustom will contain the data of map which will be in our native

Comment: Yep that is Map<String, List<Custom_object> = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); then you should properly convert it to json string with gson or whatever library you like.

Comment: argument of type is not needed in that yourBridgeMethod right?

Comment: yep I put that as example you can avoid it

Comment: Hi I need to map a readableMap object that is received from react native to its equivalent Java object in the @ReactMethod in Java. How can I achieve the same

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz, all the examples I see converts the json to a WritableMap, similar to your example. But why not just return the json string? And on the react native side use JSON.parse() to get the JavaScript object representation? Is it something I'm missing here?

Comment: just put string, and convert to JSON in Js side using JSON.parse(...)

Comment: that is valid too

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding the need of parsing the json to a ReadableMap in JavaScript and then back to json in Java, vice versa. Instead I just pas the json as a string. Is this a bad practice?

JavaScript code:

```
static methodOne(paramOne: ParamOne) {
    let paramObjectAsJson = JSON.stringify(paramOne);
    return Bridge.methodOne(paramObjectAsJson) as Promise<string>;
}
```

Java code:

```
@ReactMethod
public void methodOne(final String paramObjectAsJson, final Promise promise) {
    try {
        ParamOneJavaClass request = fromVariantJson(paramObjectAsJson);
        ...
        promise.resolve(null);
    catch(Exception e) {
        promise.reject(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private ParamOneJavaClass fromVariantJson(String json) {
    return createDefaultGson().fromJson(json, ParamOneJavaClass.class);
}

private static Gson createDefaultGson() {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    return builder.create();
}
```